# Django dynamic image path using user group

Tags: django, file-upload

I have this photo model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = ImageField(_('photo'), upload_to='upload/products')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    quality = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('quality'), default=0)
```

I want to set path based on the user group. I know i can set a callable function to `upload_to`, but in the examples i have seen, they always access to the fields of the photo instance.
I can access to `user` or `request` in my view. Can i set `upload_to` from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't provide access to *current user* in `model` due

> If you need access to the user somewhere, write a function or method 
>   which takes the user as an argument, and have your view call that 
>   function or method, passing the user. This is approximately eighty 
>   billion times simpler than coming up with threadlocal hacks to try to 
>   create a magic global user variable, results in cleaner, 
>   easier-to-understand code, reduces the likelihood of 
>   difficult-to-track bugs in the code and, best of all, is a perfectly 
>   obvious way to accomplish the task.

(from http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/44ced967d9da3500)

But you able to use hack like [django-globals](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-globals)